# How to run Spring Boot application on test server using Jenkins

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot application with the embedded Tomcat server from a jar that is generated by Gradle.

Nothing too fancy I would say, but somehow I can't get this to work the way I would like.

There are some issues here. The goal is to run the Spring Boot application on a test server so that we can do some integration tests on it. We have created some Postman tests that we'll run on Jenkins after the Spring Boot app has started.

## Run the jar artifact plain and simple

My guess was that the easiest way would be to deploy the jar to the server and run it with `java -jar my-app.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. When I run this command on localhost and go to *http://localhost:8100* I can see the website. But when I do the same thing on the server, the website does not show.

## Run the jar using a script

To automate starting and stopping the Spring Boot app I figured a script would be nice.

I created a script that should shut down all running processes and then start a new one. This script would be called after the new artifact is deployed to the test server.

```
#!/bin/sh
ps | grep my-app | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9 || true
/usr/bin/java -jar my-app.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar &
```

What happens when this script is run is the following:

First a message is displayed indicating the `ps` command is not used properly:

```
$ ./start-app

Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]

...
```

Then I would expect the Spring Boot application to start, but first I see another prompt and then the Spring Boot app starts.

```
$
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)
...
2018-09-29 18:11:45.142 ERROR 29971 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8100]]
...
```

Which says another instance is running, which can be verified by calling `ps`. And I also don't get another prompt until I press the *enter* key.

The question is: how can I get the Spring Boot application to run on it's own and to start a new instance when it is available?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that the application is not being killed.

If that server is only used for testing your application, you can kill all java processes more easily by running:

```
pkill -f "java"
```

Note that running the above will kill **all java processes**. This isn't a problem if you're just running one java application.

Here's a script that might fit your needs:

```
output=`lsof -i :8100`

if [ ${#output} != 0 ]; then
    echo "Port 8100 is already running, killing all java processes"
    pkill -f "java"
else
    echo "Port 8100 is NOT running"
fi

echo "Starting application"
java -jar yourjarfilenamehere.jar &
```

What this does is:

1. Check if the port `8100` is in use (the port that your application uses)

   - If it's in use, it kills all java processes
   - If it's NOT in use, then it does nothing
2. Run your jar file